# Microsoft Graph API query involving externalUserState C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Hi I'm trying to write a simple console app which I intend to make into a batch file and get a list of external users who were invited by email have and now they have guest accounts in our Azure tenant and they have redeemed the url that was sent to them in email. When they redeem, their ***extenalUserState*** sets to "Accepted". I want to find which ones have that status.

I was told that I have to point to beta version of the API and not v.1.0 of the graph endpoint.

I have the following rudimentary code I have written looking at various examples I could find on GitHub/MS documentation for API etc.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreateAzureADUser
{
    class Program
    {
        static string TenantDomain;
        static string TenantId;
        static string ClientId;
        static string ClientSecret;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetUsers();
            //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------\n\n");
            //GetGroupsAndMembers();
            //CreateAzureADUserNow();
        }

        private static void GetUsers()
        {
            var graphServiceClient = CreateGraphServiceClient();


            var users = graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter("userType eq 'Guest' and startswith(mail,'phs')")
                                                          .Select("id,mail,OnPremisesExtensionAttributes,userType,displayName,externalUserState")
                                                          .GetAsync()
                                                          .Result;



            Console.WriteLine("Users found: {0}", users.Count);
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("displayName: {3} \nuser id: {0} \nuser email: {1} \nExtensionAttribute8: {2}\n", item.Id, item.Mail, item.OnPremisesExtensionAttributes.ExtensionAttribute8, item.DisplayName);
            }



        }

        public static GraphServiceClient CreateGraphServiceClient()
        {
            TenantDomain = "mycompanytenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            TenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            ClientId = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
            ClientSecret = "zzzzzzzzzzzz";

            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompanytenant.onmicrosoft.com");
            var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential).Result;


            var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });

            // Use this for v.1.0 endpoint
            //return new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider);

            // Use this for connecting to beta endpoint
            return new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", delegateAuthProvider);
        }
}
}
```

When I run through the debugger, I do not see "ExternalUserState" as an attribute on the users that are returned.

How to access ExternalUserState attribute on the guest user  object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the SDK so you're using Graph v1.0, not the Beta. The SDKs are all generated from v1.0 metadata so beta properties and methods simply do not exist in the models.

From time to time there is a beta build pushed out to GitHub but it is generally a few versions behind. Currently, the latest beta SDK available seems to be [v1.12.0](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/1.12.0-beta) (for reference, the current SDK is v1.15).